# Determining the test classes in a project

Tags: java, class, test-class

I wonder is there any id or specified label to distinguish a selected class whether it is  one of the standard class declarations or test class in run-time?

EDIT: I collect the entire classes from the project. I separate abstract classes, interfaces, subclasses by looking the collection, whereas I also want to know how many classes have test behavior. In other words, how many classes are actually test classes. One more thing: I don't know these classes in advance, these are not mine!

Comment: are you talking about reflection? naming conventions? IDE settings ? what id/label? give more context.

Comment: It depends on the way you're running the tests. SureFire executes(by default, you can change it) all tests under src/test which contain "Test" in the class name.

Comment: some test classes which I have seen also contain src/, not src/test

Comment: Can't you just look for any class that has a JUnit import?

Comment: for some test classes, this approach can solve as Leo also mentioned one. I ll take a deep look them.

Answer (score 2):

Let me share with you how I like to organize my tests in eclipse :-) maybe you may find useful.

First, I create two projects, one for the app and another for the test.

[image]

The test project, of course, has a dependency on the app project

[image]

Now, let's suppose you want to add some test case, you just point to the right src dir.

[image]

So you want to create your test code without mixing app code and test code (for example, utils), just leave what's specific to the right project.

[image]

The only name convention I use is the eclipse junit default, appending the word "Test" in the end of the test class.

No need for ant scripts to deploy only the app code.

Even JUNIT dependency is restricted to the test project.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! but some names of test classes don't start or end with *test* :/

Comment: yes, but if you keep the test code in a separate project, then you'll know exactly what classes are test related and what classes are not :-)

Comment: the point is that these projects are not mine. I just analyses them. It is not allowed to change the projects directory or classes' names

Comment: if some util class is used in both your test class and app class, does it count as test or not?

Comment: Hmm.. so you say, check the imported packages of the classes?

Comment: not safe. you can use a class without adding it in the imported packages